# How can I improve the performance of this small Ruby function?

Tags: ruby

I am currently doing a Ruby challenge and get the error `Terminated due to timeout`
for some testcases where the string input is very long (10.000+ characters).

How can I improve my code?

#### Ruby challenge description

You are given a string containing characters A and B only. Your task is to change it into a string such that there are no matching adjacent characters. To do this, you are allowed to delete zero or more characters in the string.

Your task is to find the minimum number of required deletions.

For example, given the string `s = AABAAB`, remove `A` an  at positions `0` and `3` to make `s = ABAB` in  `2` deletions.

#### My function

```
def alternatingCharacters(s)
    counter = 0
    s.chars.each_with_index { |char, idx| counter += 1 if s.chars[idx + 1] == char }
    return counter
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: I didn't benchmark it, but my feeling is that invoking the block for each element of the `s.chars` array eats up a lot of time. If you don't create an interim array, but just loop over the characters, i.e. `s.size.times {|idx| char=s[idx]; next_char=s[idx+1]; ...}`, I found it to be faster on my installation (MRI Ruby, Cygwin).

Comment: Ok I see, that's faster indeed. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder whether my suggestion or the one in the anser given by iGian is faster .....

Answer (score 3):

This could be faster returning the count:

```
str.size - str.chars.chunk_while{ |a, b| a == b }.to_a.size
```

The second part uses [String#chars](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-chars) method in conjunction with [Enumerable#chunk_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while).
This way the second part groups in subarrays:

```
'aababbabbaab'.chars.chunk_while{ |a, b| a == b}.to_a
#=> [["a", "a"], ["b"], ["a"], ["b", "b"], ["a"], ["b", "b"], ["a", "a"], ["b"]]
```

Comment: ...or `str.size - str.each_char.chunk(&:itself).to_a.size`.

Answer (score 3):

Trivial if you can use [`squeeze`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-squeeze):

```
str.length - str.squeeze.length
```

Otherwise, you could try a regular expression that matches those `A` (or `B`) that  are preceded by another  `A` (or `B`):

```
str.enum_for(:scan, /(?<=A)A|(?<=B)B/).count
```

Using `enum_for` avoids the creation of the intermediate array.

Comment: You could alternatively write `str.gsub(/(?<=A)A|(?<=B)B/).count` or `str.gsub(/(.)(?=\1)/).count`. The latter covers the more general case of there being more than two unique characters in the string (e.g., `"AABCCBBBADDCCCB".gsub(/(.)(?=\1)/).count  #=> 7`).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with:

> ```
> s.chars.each_with_index { |char, idx| counter += 1 if s.chars[idx + 1] == char }
> ```

Is the fact that you don't save `chars` into a variable. `s.chars` will rip apart the string into an array of characters. The first `s.chars` call outside the loop is fine. However there is no reason to do this for each character in `s`. This means if you have a string of 10.000 characters, you'll instantiate 10.001 arrays of size 10.000.

Re-using the characters array will give you a huge performance boost:

```rb
require 'benchmark'

s  = ''
options = %w[A B]
10_000.times { s << options.sample }
```

```rb
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    counter = 0
    s.chars.each_with_index { |char, idx| counter += 1 if s.chars[idx + 1] == char }
    #           create a character array for each iteration ^
  end

  x.report do
    counter = 0
    chars = s.chars # <- only create a character array once
    chars.each_with_index { |char, idx| counter += 1 if chars[idx + 1] == char }
  end
end
```

```
       user     system      total        real
   8.279767   0.000001   8.279768 (  8.279655)
   0.002188   0.000003   0.002191 (  0.002191)
```

You could also make use of enumerator methods like [`each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [`count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) to simplify the code, this doesn't increase performance cost a lot, but makes the code a lot more readable.

```rb
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    counter = 0
    chars = s.chars
    chars.each_with_index { |char, idx| counter += 1 if chars[idx + 1] == char }
  end

  x.report do
    s.each_char.each_cons(2).count { |a, b| a == b }
    #  ^ using each_char instead of chars to avoid
    #    instantiating a character array
  end
end
```

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.002923   0.000000   0.002923 (  0.002920)
   0.003995   0.000000   0.003995 (  0.003994)
```